# is there a way for Menubar to display only battery percentage?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

is there a way to see only the percentage, I dont really care about the small battery image and I dont need it. Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

[iStats Menus 5](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) has various monitoring widgets for the menu bar, one being a  battery indicator. Could be helpful?